# Refresh the page to see changes in list view?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, workflow-activity

I am using SharePoint **2010**. I created a simple workflow. Do I always need to refresh the page in order to see the workflow's progress on the view?

For example, I have a workflow that is started when an item is created. I create an item in the list. After creating the item, I don't see anything under the Workflow column. I need to **refresh** the page for the view to **update**. This is **not** very user-friendly.

I inspected the Actions in SPD and I can't seem to find a suitable action like **Refresh the List**. I believe the behavior is the same with SharePoint **2013**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lester, list/library view does not auto-update, which from my perspective is a good thing, as it can be a CPU and I/O intensive operation.

You're not seeing anything in the workflow column immediately after creating the item because the workflow instance related to that item has not been created yet.  Once it's created the Workflow column would be populated upon refresh (...as you noted) or re-entry into the list/library.

There isn't anything you can do OOB to change this behavior.  And I would recommend not attempting to change it...it doesn't seem worth the effort.

Comment: No, I wouldn't say it's a performance issue. I merely pointed out that auto-refreshing a list view would probably be a bad idea.  It's really the inherent behavior of a browser-based UI. You really wouldn't want the whole page to refresh...believe me, that would be annoying. So you'd have to implement a capability, say AJAX, that would only update certain UI elements.  Or do something client-side with jQuery.  Either way, a lot of work.  It want real-time monitoring of your worklows I would suggest looking at a product like K2 or the like.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of AJAX. Thanks, I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question, then you can add the email activity at the end of the workflow. SO that you can get the email and know the workflow is completed.

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. What I mean is, the view does not show the actual progress of the workflow. For example, if it is **In Progress** state or **Completed**. You need to refresh the page in order to see the actual progress.